# Python TypeError: string indices must be integers JSON issue

Tags: python

I'm trying to get data from json and all data inside aaData key and there is a lot and I'm trying to loop through to get them but I'm facing error. Please help me. here is the following code:

**JSON**

```
{
   "sEcho":1,
   "iTotalRecords":3122,
   "iTotalDisplayRecords":3122,
   "aaData":[
      {
         "Id":890001,
         "Category":"Personbil",
         "LicenceNumber":"GDJ97S",
         "LicenceNumberLink":"GDJ97S",
         "Manufacturer":"Audi RS6 AVANT PERFORMANCE",
         "ManufacturerLink":"Audi RS6 AVANT PERFORMANCE",
         "CoachDescription":"",
         "TheftLocation":"Stockholms län",
         "TheftLocationLink":"Stockholms län",
         "TheftDate":"2020-10-28",
         "TheftDateLink":"2020-10-28",
         "Artist":null,
         "ArtistLink":"",
         "Name":null,
         "NameLink":"",
         "Type":null,
         "TypeLink":"",
         "SerialNumberLink":""
      },
```

**CODE**

```
def parse_form(self, response):
    results = json.loads(response.text)
    for result in results:
        license_number = result['aaData'][0]['LicenceNumber']

        yield {
            'License Number': license_number
        }
```

Comment: I think the loop is iterating over the wrong thing. Try this: `for result in results['aaData']:
        license_number = result['LicenceNumber']`

Comment: It's Working. Thanks a lot. I'll post your answer and mark it :)

Answer (score 0):

**Answered by @cs95**

```
def parse_form(self, response):
    results = json.loads(response.text)
    for result in results['aaData']:
        license_number = result['LicenceNumber']

        yield {
            'License Number': license_number
        }
```